# Access/Pass variable between windows form and DataSet TableAdapter SQL where clause

Tags: winforms, dataset, rdlc, tableadapter

In Visual Studio 2010, I have a windows forms application frmMain.cs with a ComboBox. From the form itself I can access its value with cmbxYear.SelectedValue. I also have a DataSet.xsd file to bind to an rdlc report to a TableAdapter to present view data. The TableAdapter has a SelectCommand that takes SQL code.  I need to get the value of cmbxYear.SelectedValue into the WHERE clause of the TableAdapter.
Does anyone know how I can access/pass the variable value from the form into the DataSet TableAdapter SelectCommand WHERE clause?

Comment: I am open to other ideas of how to filter an rdlc report with a variable defined on the windows form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using the OleDb provider for Oracle. 
The bind variable should be a question mark ? not :DEPTCODE

The bind variable :DEPTCODE would be valid for System.Data.OracleClient

See full walk through here: http://www.fullstackbusinessdesign.com/forums/ORA-01008.html

Many thanks to Prashant Kumar for this solution.
http://forums.asp.net/members/Prashant%20Kumar.aspx